# Finding Specific Means and Medians in R

Tags: r, statistics, analysis

I am working on a project for school in R that is looking at swimming data compiled up of 8 different teams looking at each of the 13 events, over 6 years. I have over 8700 rows of data that I have appended and am trying to find out how to draw the specific means that I am looking for. For example, I would like to look at the progression of mean times for team 1 for event 3 for men. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49848192/edit) your question to include some sample data (use e.g. `dput`). Also provide expected output to help us understand which summary statistics you'd like to calculate for which group.

Comment: The question is self-contradictory: first you describe your dataset as *8 different teams looking at each of the 13 events, over 6 years*  then you ask about *men*, implying another categorical variable, sex.

Answer (score 0):

You can subset your data-frame to only include those variables, e.g.

```
ss = subset(df, team == 1 & event == 3)
mean(ss$times)
```